# How to set min value for field in form?

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x

I have form with integer field - price.

```
$builder->add('list',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'required' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ])
            ->add('price',
            IntegerType::class,
            [
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ]);
```

How to set, for example, for validation i need min value for price 0 or greater?

I tried this one, but it's not work:

```
'constraints' => [
new GreaterThanOrEqual(50)
 ],
```

Thanks for all help.

controller Action

```
 public function getProductAction(Request $request)
    {
        $variables = $request->get('list');

        $price = $request->get('price');

        $form = $this->createForm(ProductForm::class, null, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'allow_extra_fields' => true]);

        $form->submit(['variables' => $variables, 'prices' => $price]);

        if(!$form->isValid()) {

            $errors = '';

            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
                $errors = $error->getMessage();
            }

            return new JsonResponse([
                'errors' => $errors
            ],Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {

            $product = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Product::class)
                ->findByListAndPrice($list, $price);

            if (!$product) {
                return new JsonResponse([
                    'errors' => 'Product not found.'
                ],Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            return new JsonResponse($product);
        }
    }
```

Form not validate, and don't show errors, $form->isValid() === true

Comment: please explain more and show the error message.

Comment: you are submitting your form value manually, in this case, you could try constraints in entity instead of formType here is doc [GreaterThanOrEqual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThanOrEqual.html#basic-usage)

Comment: @habibun and how to validate when submitting manually?

Comment: please check previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3533 you can use `min` and `max` for the `IntegerType` even though the documentation might not mention this.

```
$builder->add('list',
    CollectionType::class,
    [
        'required' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'error_bubbling' => true,
    ])
    ->add('price',
    IntegerType::class,
    [
        'required' => false,
        'error_bubbling' => true,
        /*'min' => 50*/
        'attr' => [
          'min' => 50
        ]
    ]);
```

EDIT: According to the documentation the 'min' property has to be inside 'attr' tag. This will add the min inside the input in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RangeType instead of IntegerType.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RangeType;
// ...

$builder->add('list',
    CollectionType::class,
    [
        'required' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'error_bubbling' => true,
    ])
    ->add('price',
    RangeType::class,
    [
        'required' => false,
        'error_bubbling' => true,
        'min' => 0,
        'max' => 50
    ]);
```